# phantomjs SVG server response

Tags: d3.js, phantomjs

I've a phantomjs server which loads a page do some d3 visualization. I was able to do the visualization things work but my problem is how to write the final html to response. My code is below.

```
// server.js

service = server.listen(8124, function (request, response) {
console.log('Request received at ' + new Date());

response.statusCode = 200;
response.headers = {
    'Cache': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
    'Content': ''
};

var req = JSON.parse(request.post);

visualize();
response.write(??) // 

});

// app.js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

function visualize() {
   page.open("./index.html", function() {
   var ret = page.evaluate(function() {
         // Do some SVG work
       });
       console.log(ret); // <svg><g></g></svg
       // at this point I am sure that the ret is an html svg element. How can I write this to response?
   });            

}
```

Comment: Do you use the phantom-node plugin from nodejs?

Comment: No. I don't think I need a plugin. I just need to return ret to response.

Comment: I asked how you use phantom and also where do you want to return it to? Do you use node.js? Do you use the phantom-node plugin for node.js to run your phantom script? Since this is not clear from your question!

Comment: I was able to do it using node-phantom plugin. It was pure phantomjs but I converted it to nodeJS + node-phantom. Now I can get the response. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction :)